# how to get client roles through keycloak in airflow correctly?

Tags: airflow, keycloak

trying to set up sso in airflow via keycloak

the user is displayed in the airflow admin panel, but no role Admin is assigned to him during registration, apparently the client role is incorrectly given
in the airflow config

```
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
 {
   'name': 'keycloak',
   'icon': 'fa-key',
   'token_key': 'access_token',
   'remote_app': {
     'api_base_url': 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/airflow/protocol/openid-connect',
     'jwks_uri': 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/airflow/protocol/openid-connect/certs',
     'client_kwargs': {
       'scope': 'openid profile email roles',
     },
     'request_token_url': None,
     'access_token_url': 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/airflow/protocol/openid-connect/token',
     'authorize_url': 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/airflow/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
     'client_id': 'airflow-client',
     'client_secret': 'bf9fgf-4gff-4fgfg-agf-fgfg3ad'
    }
  }
]
```

in config keycloak
[image]
[image]
[image]
if you do evaluate in admin console

```
{
  "exp": 16916645656059,
  "iat": 16915464566635656759,
  "jti": "a7d2afac-1c25-4837-9d0f-8770f0377bde",
  "iss": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/airflow",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "448dfgdfgf0d0-dfg-dgf-99dga7-gddgfg",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "airflow-client",
  "session_state": "dgsdgf6d-5adb-41a6-a1e9-7553f194cc4b",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "airflow-client": {
      "roles": [
        "Admin"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "fdgdg dfgdfgdfg",
  "preferred_username": "gg",
  "given_name": "fdgdg",
  "family_name": "dfgdfgdfg",
  "email": "gg@gmail.com",
  "air-roles": [
    "Admin"
  ]
}
```

[image]
if you make a regular role and create a client role, and then specify it in the airflow configuration, then registration is successful, but I need to do it through client roles